# How to multiselect items in flatlist react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How to multi select and highlight the components in a react native flatlist. I have checked the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist). But it is bit confusing can anybody help me. I have done single select using this method.Could any one modify this to a multi select.I will give the snack link here where i have done the [single select](https://snack.expo.io/@ambadyajay/107eed)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const Data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Sile',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: 'Clementia',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first_name: 'Brita',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    first_name: 'Duke',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    first_name: 'Hedvig',
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    first_name: 'Paulie',
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    first_name: 'Munmro',
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    first_name: 'Dyanna',
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    first_name: 'Shanta',
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    first_name: 'Bambi',
  },
];

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItem: null,
    };
  }

  onPressHandler(id) {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: id });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          extraData={this.state.selectedItem} //Must implemented
          //horizontal={true}
          data={Data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPressHandler(item.id)}>
              <Card
                style={
                  this.state.selectedItem === item.id
                    ? {
                        padding: 10,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        backgroundColor: '#000000',
                      }
                    : {
                        padding: 10,
                        borderRadius: 5,
                        backgroundColor: '#a1a1a1',
                      }
                }>
                <Text>{item.first_name}</Text>
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

this is the sample data

Comment: What you mean by select, do you want to apply any class to any item in flatlist for highlighting it ?

Comment: Highlight the component and save the id to  a state.

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your question please check.

Comment: where have you edited on snack or in my question reference.

Comment: I have created new snack link please refer my answer I have mentioned in it. If its correct please mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have made some changes and made your flatlist as multiselect. Please visit this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@tejas1991/35caa9).

I have made below changes for making this as multiselect:

- Added dummy data in state & passed it to flatlist's data.
- On item press iterate data and for corresponding item set `item.selected=true`.
- Inside flatlist's renderItem if `item.selected==true` then show selection else remove selection.

Please check and let me know.

Comment: could you give me an example. And i need to select multiple components.

Comment: I purposefully didnt write code so that it would be easy for you to write code & understand on my answer's logic. What you mean my multiple component ? Any item in flatlist will be a common component right ?

Comment: i have more than one data in the array so i need to select more than one component .In the flat list doc it shows how to select multiple data but its hard to understand.

Comment: Can you edit question and give example of how your flatlist items will be in detail bcoz as per your question it seems to be one flatlist only.

Comment: I will edit in that code and will update my answer.

Comment: And could please tell me how to access the selected values.

Comment: How to access selected values means ?

Comment: The id's of selected items.I couldn't get the values from renderData

Comment: Just iterate state.data and get those items whose selected is true. Here you will get multilist of items then you can process them.

Comment: @ambady: I have added new method getSelectedItems() which will print selected item's ids. I have updated code in same fiddle which is present in my answer. Click print selection to print selected ids after selection.

Comment: couldn't find it in the above link.!!

Comment: Its same link as https://snack.expo.io/@tejas1991/flatlist-multiselect

Comment: could anyone change this to functional component ?

Answer (score 1):

check this logic,

```
 ...
     this.state = {
          clientsArray: clientsArray,
          selectedClients: []
        };
    //'clientsArray' is your data array
 ...

  _renderCell = ({ item, index }) => {
    const { selectedClients, clientsArray } = this.state;
    let isSelected =
      selectedClients.filter(o => {
        return o.id === item.id;
      }).length > 0
        ? true
        : false;

   //change your UI based on the 'isSelected' value
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        activeOpacity={Constants.ACTIVE_OPACITY}
        onPress={() => {
          this._didSelectClient(item);
        }}
      >
       {
         //Your component
       }
      </TouchableOpacity>
 }


_didSelectClient = selectedItem => {
    let selectedClients = this.state.selectedClients;
    let isItemSelected =
      selectedClients.filter(item => {
        return item.id.includes(selectedItem.id);
      }).length > 0
        ? true
        : false;

    if (isItemSelected) {
      const index = selectedClients.findIndex(
        obj => obj.id === selectedItem.id
      );
      selectedClients.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      selectedClients.push(selectedItem);
    }

    this.setState({ selectedClients });
  };

render() {
    ...
    <FlatList
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
     data={clientsArray}
     renderItem={this._renderCell}
     keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
     extraData={this.props}
     ListEmptyComponent={this._renderEmptyComponent}
    />
    ...
}
```